# Software Access Software

Tags: monitoring, system-monitor

I work for a mid-size company, and we're starting to look into behavioural analytics for our staff ("How do they do this, that and this"?), in relation to access control and data usage. This is both for security and  to try and improve overall business process.

Therefore, we are attempting to implement local file server monitoring to see specific functions performed by staff, such as:

1. Who accessed this file;
2. This user deleted a file;
3. This user renamed a file;
4. This user copied the file etc.

The benefits are we have a product that manages, in real time, file access and performs informative reporting - user access, user behaviour analysis, file breach, sensitive data leakage and other functions.

We know of tools such as [Varonis](https://www.varonis.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=varonis&utm_content=varonis&utm_campaign=varonis-search-brand&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkKPVBRDtARIsAA2CG6FCwN7Okq8XSiyTUnmRRoprW8xQssDG4y6pIWSblk9ChSBftktwiJsaAlRxEALw_wcB), [Lepide](https://www.lepide.com/) and [Netwrix](https://www.netwrix.com/auditor9.5.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwkKPVBRDtARIsAA2CG6HR6xeoSU_VcFjdwSj_l8vk32rpiwrjlolc_eCXIUEeZYSFkRsNYjQaAl2kEALw_wcB) and have trialled them - rather nice - however, the price unfortunately is out of question - for Lepide, it is something like $630USD/file server a year. Multiply this by 85 and we're at $50,000.00 per year just for this tool.

I was aware of [Auditing File Access using windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/08/26/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers/), however this has many limitations:

1. Relies on a script - I.E. we may need to add hosts to the script for example
2. Non-GUI products may deter other staff from usage (HelpDesk and Management for example)
3. Requires several additional scripts to perform monitoring reports.

Requirements for a successful product:

1. Must be capable of monitoring several file servers;
2. Must have reporting capabilities;
3. Must be autonomous;

Preferences:

1. Free, or single purchase;
2. Run on Windows, however, Linux is fine;
3. Has a GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, if you have already found a solution to your problem in 1.5 years. But maybe this information will be useful for other users.
"10-Strike connection monitor"  monitors usage of admin and regular network shares on PCs or file servers. 
From their [website](https://www.10-strike.com/connectionmonitor/):

> - Monitor Access to Shares, Files, and Folders
> - Audit User Access, Monitor Changes in Shared Files and Folders, and Generate Alerts
> - Log Access to Shares, Files, and Directories.
> - Alert on Suspicious User Activity
> - Monitor File/Folder Changing
> - Monitor User Activity
> - Disconnect users who download large files automatically according to the blacklist settings.